# Why is [user] again suspended?

Tags: discussion, suspensions

I would like to know why [user] is suspended again, this time until Ago 2014.

Can anybody explain to me what happened?

Answer (score 10):

As we have said repeatedly, we (moderators) do not share information about specific suspensions with anyone except other moderators and the SE team.* This means that the moderators will not explain to you what happened, and nobody else on this site knows what happened. While other non-moderator users may be able to give you examples of behavior that *could* have led to a suspension, they don't know what actually *did* lead to the suspension.

I can't speak for the Stack Exchange team, although I highly doubt they will discuss specific cases, either. Though they do frequently *review* suspensions internally, to make sure nothing untoward is going on.

Generally speaking, though, I will say that suspensions are imposed for violations of the site rules as outlined in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help). The first two items on the [behavior page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) ("be honest" and "be nice") cover most cases.

---

*If a suspended user decides to reveal information about their own suspension, the moderators may then be permitted to respond. But as a rule, we tend not to do so because we've found that it rarely leads to anything productive.

Comment: When you say "we" do you mean the moderators? May be the question is addressed to anyone(not just the moderators) who might know and has no problem saying it.

Comment: @MBN Yes, only moderators are prohibited from discussing specific suspensions in public (more or less). For other users, it is only strongly recommended not to do so, but not required. However, nobody other than the moderators and the SE team has access to the information that is used to determine suspensions. So although other users may be able to speculate based on things they've seen, I can guarantee that nobody else knows why a specific user was suspended. (The message sent to the suspended user does have a basic reason for the suspension, but not a full detailed explanation.)

Comment: But if you are prohibited to discuss it in public, that doesn't mean you cannot tell it to someone in private. So he, someone other than the moderators and SE team, could have the information.

Comment: @MBN by "public" I meant anyone other than moderators or the SE team. Sorry for the confusion. I'll clarify this in the answer.

Comment: @MBN You are right, I know that moderators won't give that information. I was asking for anyone who could have been present during the horrible felony, and perhaps could tell.